# Not Sure How to Convert User's Input (String) to Acceptable Data Type

Tags: java

I have four files:

LibraryPatron.java

```
/** A class that maintains a shopping cart for an online store.
@author Frank M. Carrano
@version 4.0
*/ // Data fields are: Name, Library card number, Street, City, Zip
import java.util.*;

public class LibraryPatron
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{


Patron[] Patron =
   {
       new Patron("Name", "Library Card", "Address", "City", "Zip Code"),

new Patron("Name", "Library Card", "Address", "City", "Zip Code")};

LinkedInterface libraryPatronList = new LinkedBag();

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter name:");

if (libraryPatronList.contains(name))
{   
System.out.println ("Patron is in system.");
String info = libraryPatronList.getData(name);

for (String field: info.split(","))
System.out.println(field);
}

else
System.out.println ("Patron is not in system.");
}
}
```

Patron.java

```
/** A class of items for sale.
@author Frank M. Carrano
@version 4.0
*/

public class Patron // Data fields are: Name, Library card number, Street, City, Zip
{
private String name;
private String libraryCard;
private String street;
private String city;
private String zip;

public Patron(String nameOfPatron, String libraryCardNumber, String streetName, String cityName, String zipName)
{
name = nameOfPatron;
libraryCard = libraryCardNumber;
street = streetName;
city = cityName;
zip = zipName;
} // end constructor


public String getName()
{
return name;
} // end getDescription

@Override

public boolean equals (Object patron2)
{
Patron tempPatron;
tempPatron = (Patron) patron2;
return (name.equals (tempPatron.getName()));
}

public String toString()
{
   return name + "," + libraryCard + "," + street + "," + city + "," + zip;

} // end toString
} // end Item
```

LinkedBag.java

```
public final class LinkedBag implements LinkedInterface
{
Node firstNode;
int numberOfEntries;


// Simple constructor
public LinkedBag()
{
firstNode = null;
numberOfEntries = 0;
} // end default constructor


/** Locates a given entry within this bag.
@param anEntry The entry to be located.
@return A reference to the node if located, or null otherwise. */
private Node getReferenceTo (T anEntry)
{
Node currentNode = firstNode;
boolean found = false;
while (!found && currentNode != null)
{
if (anEntry.equals (currentNode.data))
found = true;
else
currentNode = currentNode.next;
}
return currentNode;
}


/** Tests whether this bag contains a given entry.
@param anEntry The entry to locate.
@return True if the bag contains anEntry, or false otherwise. */
public boolean contains(T anEntry)
{
Node currentNode = getReferenceTo (anEntry);
return !(currentNode == null);
} // end


/** Retrieves all entries that are in this bag.
@return A newly allocated array of all the entries in this bag. */
public T[] toArray()
{
@SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
T[] result = (T[]) new Object[numberOfEntries];
int index = 0;
Node currentNode = firstNode;
while (currentNode != null)
{
result [index] = currentNode.data;
++index;
currentNode = currentNode.next;
}
return result;
}

private class Node
{
private T data;
private Node next;

// Two contructors.
private Node (T dataPortion)
{
this (dataPortion, null);
}

private Node (T dataPortion, Node nextNode)
{
data = dataPortion;
next = nextNode;   
}
}

/** Returns information in node containing anEntry in String form
* @param anEntry The entry to be searched for.
* @return String value of data in node if found, or empty string otherwise */

public String getData(T anEntry)
{
   String result = "";

   Node currentNode = getReferenceTo (anEntry);
   if (currentNode != null)
   {
       result = currentNode.data.toString();
       }
   return result;
   } // end getData

} // end LinkedBag
```

LinkedInterface.java

```
/**
An interface that describes the operations of a bag of objects.
@author Frank M. Carrano
@version 4.0
*/
public interface LinkedInterface
{

   public boolean contains(T name);

   public String getData(T anEntry);
} // end BagInterface
```

My question is regarding the LibraryPatron.java code I have up until now.

I'm trying to take the user's input and scan through the Patron's list I created in order to verify if what the user's input is part of my Linkedlist, but I don't know how to convert from String and use the methods I need. If the user's input is part of the Linkedlist I created ahead of time, it will return the user's info back including their name, library card number, address, city, and zip code. Any advice or guidance would appreciated, thank you!

Comment: To convert from a string to an integer, use the static method Integer.parseString(str)

Answer (score 0):

1. The LinkedBag class does not have methods to add something . 
   You will have to add code to do that to the LinkedInterface and to the LinkedBag . Something along the lines of

   `public void add(T anEntity)`
2. Fill The linkedBag with the patron that you have created .
3. `name`  in LibraryPatron is undefined . That will have to change to something like this
   `Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in);
   String name = input. nextLine();`